# Is there a json schema for the SurveyMonkey API?

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, surveymonkey

Using the SurveyMonkey API, I'm writing some Java code to do survey analysis. The survey monkey API returns JSON data. I would like to generate some Java classes so I get some type safety and conciseness while I'm manipulating the data. I've had no luck finding a json schema for the Survey Monkey API.

So, I'm looking into tools that generate a schema from json directly, but obviously that will be less desirable than getting it from the canonical source.

The question:

Can anyone recommend a tool-chain that will take me from a set of json examples to a set of java classes that can be used to read an manipulate that json. This might include the intermediate step of generating a schema, but the end-game I'm after is the classes.

If anyone knows of a schema for the API, though, that would be even better.

Comment: When you say JSON schema, do you just mean something like this on the developer portal? https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_survey_list

Comment: @MilesCederman-Haysom, no. I mean a json-schema that defines the shape of the valid responses from that API call. Something like as described at http://json-schema.org

Comment: Aha, I don't think they offer anything like that, and while I've seen a .Net library that does what you want, I haven't seen a java one. I'll update if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go with polljoy, it's Opensource and I have already integreat it on one of my site and it's working perfectly, you can find it out one below menioned link.

[Polljoy](https://demo.polljoy.com/integrate)